# Count clicks and add to input

Tags: angularjs

First of all I am very new in Angular JS.

I have a list of items and by clicking on each one, it should be added to the table. The items are stored in a json file.

If the click event repeated several times the counter input which is located on the table must increases.

```
<ul class="list-inline" >
<li ng-repeat="food in foods" class="food_list">

<img class="img-box" src="images/{{ food.food_photo }}" ng-click = 'addRow(food)'><br/><span>{{food.food_name}}</span>

 </li>
 </ul>

<table class="table" id="table-right">
<tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th class="hidden-print">Delete</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
<td>{{row.food_name}}</td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control"  ng-model="row.food_count"></td>
<td>{{row.food_cost}}</td>
<td class="hidden-print"><button class="btn btn-info hidden-print"  data-ng-click="removeRow($index)">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

```
app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

$scope.rows = [];

$scope.addRow = function(obj) {

    $scope.foodname = obj.id;
    $scope.foodprice = obj.price;

    $scope.rows.push(obj);

    $scope.counter++;
}

}]);
```

Could you please help me? Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the complete code (or put the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link)?

Comment: @pahan Here is the fiddle link but I couldn't add JSON files. https://jsfiddle.net/sk4kh3g3/

Comment: It's difficult to see what you've done without the JSON files. Can you add them also? Also, it's always better to keep scripting code separated from the DOM

Comment: @pahan Its updated.

Comment: @HekmatSarwarzade it is very unclear what you actually want, but looking at your code `$scope.counter++;` you are incrementing this global counter instead of 'obj.food_count++'. Please provide the sample json data with current function working

Comment: @amansinghgusain I updated the fiddle. It's obvious now.

Comment: @HekmatSarwarzade I think you updated the wrong jsfiddle. I don't see any changes

Comment: @pahan Sorry! 
https://jsfiddle.net/sk4kh3g3/37/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nhdSYYM8Ow&list=PLLOIlS9k6DGx9t3LG1E5shOlPYWxmWc2z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand that `food_count` property of a `row` object is the variable that should be updated on repetitive clicks. Updating any other `$scope` variables won't change row specific data because your view is bound to `$scope.rows` object.

Your `addRow` function should look like this.

```
$scope.addRow = function(obj) {
      if($scope.rows.indexOf(obj) >= 0){ // if this obj already exist
         $scope.rows[$scope.rows.indexOf(obj)].food_count++;    
      }
      else
         $scope.rows.push(obj);
   }
```

Then the objects of `$scope.foods` should have a property called `food_count` to display.

```
$scope.foods = [
        {food_name:'Jani',food_cost:'10', food_count:0},
        {food_name:'Hege',food_cost:'8',food_count:0},
        {food_name:'Kai',food_cost:'5',food_count:0}]
```

[solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pahan_silva/se3juhmt)

Comment: Thank You so Much.